# How to parent programs to tkinter windows

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ms-word

I've been working quite a bit with tkinter in Python.  I was wondering if there is a way to combine another program into my python GUI script.  Here is specifically what I am trying to accomplish:

- Python GUI Opens
- Left side of GUI is custom content (buttons etc.)
- Right side is parented MS Word document (When I move the root window the MS Word document moves accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

In a very, very limited sense you can embed a very few applications on linux, but for all intents and purposes you simply cannot embed a non-tkinter graphical application inside a tkinter window.